# Access too many fields defined - What is the limit?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016, union-all

I have read elsewhere on StackOverflow that the limit for Union Queries is 255 fields across all queries you are trying to Union. I am a bit confused, as I have one with 1078 total fields (77 across 14 queries) and it joins together fine. I have attempted to update the fields being displayed, and have gone up to 1274 total fields (91 now, across 14 queries). The first 1078 Union works but not the updated 1274 Union.

My confusion comes from the other threads where I have read 255 is the max number of fields across ALL queries in the union. The first one should not join then, but it is and has been. I was skeptical of the field limit even existing until I got this error today. Insight would be much appreciated, below are the two Union queries with the **second** being the troublesome one. I have cut them off to just the first Union ALL as putting all of the SQL in there takes my post to 70,000 something characters.

**Working Union:**

```
SELECT Qry_ScheduledItems.Sales_Order_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Customer_Order_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Customer_Name, Qry_ScheduledItems.Ship_To_Location, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Created, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Due, Qry_ScheduledItems.Part_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Quantity_Ordered, Qry_JobTicket.Pcs_Ordered, Qry_ScheduledItems.Unit_of_Measure, Qry_ScheduledItems.RIP_Footage, Qry_ScheduledItems.Mould_Footage, "" AS Previous_Operation, "" AS Previous_Date_Ran, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation1 AS Current_Operation, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled1 AS Date_Scheduled, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran1 AS Date_Ran, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation2 AS Next_Operation, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled2 AS Next_Operation_Date, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran2 AS Next_Operation_Date_Ran, Qry_JobTicket.Raw_Material, Qry_JobTicket.RIP_Width, Qry_JobTicket.BD_FTG, Qry_JobTicket.Resaw_Passes, Qry_JobTicket.Yield_Cut, Qry_JobTicket.Lumber_Notes, Qry_JobTicket.Sheet_Size, Qry_JobTicket.Optimal_RIP_Size, Qry_JobTicket.Required_RIP_Size, Qry_JobTicket.Off_Fall, Qry_JobTicket.Cuts_Per_Sheet, Qry_JobTicket.Pieces, Qry_JobTicket.Sheets_Needed, Qry_ScheduledItems.RIP_Quantity, Qry_JobTicket.Profile_Size, Qry_JobTicket.Number_Of_Passes, Qry_JobTicket.Moulder_Notes, Qry_ScheduledItems.Mould_Quantity, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Color1, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Slit1, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_SQFTG1, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Color2, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Slit2, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_SQFTG2, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Color3, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Slit3, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_SQFTG3, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Color1, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Slit1, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_SQFTG1, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Color2, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Slit2, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_SQFTG2, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Color3, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Slit3, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_SQFTG3, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Color4, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Slit4, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_SQFTG4, Qry_ScheduledItems.Wrap_Quantity, Qry_JobTicket.Finish_Number, Qry_JobTicket.Step1, Qry_JobTicket.Step2, Qry_JobTicket.Step3, Qry_JobTicket.Step4, Qry_JobTicket.Step5, Qry_JobTicket.Step6, Qry_JobTicket.Step7, Qry_JobTicket.Step8, Qry_JobTicket.Step9, Qry_JobTicket.Step10, Qry_JobTicket.Paint_Notes, Qry_ScheduledItems.Paint_Quantity, Qry_JobTicket.Assembly_Notes, Qry_JobTicket.Package_Notes, Qry_ScheduledItems.Pack_Quantity, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped
FROM Qry_JobTicket INNER JOIN Qry_ScheduledItems ON Qry_JobTicket.Sales_Order_Number = Qry_ScheduledItems.Sales_Order_Number
WHERE (((Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation1) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled1) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran1) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null))

UNION ALL SELECT Qry_ScheduledItems.Sales_Order_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Customer_Order_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Customer_Name, Qry_ScheduledItems.Ship_To_Location, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Created, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Due, Qry_ScheduledItems.Part_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Quantity_Ordered, Qry_JobTicket.Pcs_Ordered, Qry_ScheduledItems.Unit_of_Measure, Qry_ScheduledItems.RIP_Footage, Qry_ScheduledItems.Mould_Footage, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation1 AS Previous_Operation, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran1 AS Previous_Date_Ran, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation2 AS Current_Operation, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled2 AS Date_Scheduled, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran2 AS Date_Ran, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation3 AS Next_Operation, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled3 AS Next_Operation_Date, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran3 AS Next_Operation_Date_Ran, Qry_JobTicket.Raw_Material, Qry_JobTicket.RIP_Width, Qry_JobTicket.BD_FTG, Qry_JobTicket.Resaw_Passes, Qry_JobTicket.Yield_Cut, Qry_JobTicket.Lumber_Notes, Qry_JobTicket.Sheet_Size, Qry_JobTicket.Optimal_RIP_Size, Qry_JobTicket.Required_RIP_Size, Qry_JobTicket.Off_Fall, Qry_JobTicket.Pieces, Qry_JobTicket.Cuts_Per_Sheet, Qry_JobTicket.Sheets_Needed, Qry_ScheduledItems.RIP_Quantity, Qry_JobTicket.Profile_Size, Qry_JobTicket.Number_Of_Passes, Qry_JobTicket.Moulder_Notes, Qry_ScheduledItems.Mould_Quantity, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Color1, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Slit1, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_SQFTG1, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Color2, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Slit2, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_SQFTG2, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Color3, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Slit3, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_SQFTG3, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Color1, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Slit1, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_SQFTG1, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Color2, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Slit2, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_SQFTG2, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Color3, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Slit3, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_SQFTG3, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Color4, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Slit4, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_SQFTG4, Qry_ScheduledItems.Wrap_Quantity, Qry_JobTicket.Finish_Number, Qry_JobTicket.Step1, Qry_JobTicket.Step2, Qry_JobTicket.Step3, Qry_JobTicket.Step4, Qry_JobTicket.Step5, Qry_JobTicket.Step6, Qry_JobTicket.Step7, Qry_JobTicket.Step8, Qry_JobTicket.Step9, Qry_JobTicket.Step10, Qry_JobTicket.Paint_Notes, Qry_ScheduledItems.Paint_Quantity, Qry_JobTicket.Assembly_Notes, Qry_JobTicket.Package_Notes, Qry_ScheduledItems.Pack_Quantity, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped
FROM Qry_JobTicket INNER JOIN Qry_ScheduledItems ON Qry_JobTicket.Sales_Order_Number = Qry_ScheduledItems.Sales_Order_Number
WHERE (((Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation2) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled2) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran2) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null))
```

**Broken Union:**

```
SELECT Qry_ScheduledItems.Sales_Order_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Customer_Order_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Customer_Name, Qry_ScheduledItems.Ship_To_Location, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Created, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Due, Qry_ScheduledItems.Part_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Quantity_Ordered, Qry_JobTicket.Pcs_Ordered, Qry_ScheduledItems.Unit_of_Measure, Qry_ScheduledItems.RIP_Footage, Qry_ScheduledItems.Mould_Footage, Null AS Previous_Operation, Null AS Previous_Date_Ran, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation1 AS Operation, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled1 AS Date_Scheduled, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran1 AS Date_Ran, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation2 AS Next_Operation, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled2 AS Next_Operation_Date, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran2 AS Next_Operation_Date_Ran, Qry_JobTicket.Raw_Material, Qry_JobTicket.RIP_Width, Qry_JobTicket.BD_FTG, Qry_JobTicket.Resaw_Passes, Qry_JobTicket.Yield_Cut, Qry_JobTicket.Lumber_Notes, Qry_JobTicket.Sheet_Size, Qry_JobTicket.Optimal_RIP_Size, Qry_JobTicket.Required_RIP_Size, Qry_JobTicket.Off_Fall, Qry_JobTicket.Cuts_Per_Sheet, Qry_JobTicket.Pieces, Qry_JobTicket.Sheets_Needed, Qry_ScheduledItems.RIP_Quantity, Qry_JobTicket.Profile_Size, Qry_JobTicket.Moulder_Number, Qry_JobTicket.Number_Of_Passes, Qry_JobTicket.Moulder_Notes, Qry_ScheduledItems.Mould_Quantity, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Number1, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Color1, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Slit1, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_SQFTG1, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Number2, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Color2, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Slit2, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_SQFTG2, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Number3, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Color3, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Slit3, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_SQFTG3, Qry_ScheduledItems.Wrap_Quantity, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Number1, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Color1, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Slit1, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_SQFTG1, Qry_JobTicket.Foil1_Number_Slits, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Number2, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Color2, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Slit2, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_SQFTG2, Qry_JobTicket.Foil2_Number_Slits, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Number3, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Color3, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Slit3, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_SQFTG3, Qry_JobTicket.Foil3_Number_Slits, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Number4, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Color4, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Slit4, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_SQFTG4, Qry_JobTicket.Foil4_Number_Slits, Qry_JobTicket.[Wrap/Foil_Notes], Qry_JobTicket.Finish_Number, Qry_JobTicket.Step1, Qry_JobTicket.Step2, Qry_JobTicket.Step3, Qry_JobTicket.Step4, Qry_JobTicket.Step5, Qry_JobTicket.Step6, Qry_JobTicket.Step7, Qry_JobTicket.Step8, Qry_JobTicket.Step9, Qry_JobTicket.Step10, Qry_JobTicket.Paint_Notes, Qry_ScheduledItems.Paint_Quantity, Qry_JobTicket.Assembly_Notes, Qry_JobTicket.Package_Notes, Qry_JobTicket.Order_Notes, Qry_ScheduledItems.Pack_Quantity, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped
FROM Qry_JobTicket INNER JOIN Qry_ScheduledItems ON Qry_JobTicket.Sales_Order_Number = Qry_ScheduledItems.Sales_Order_Number
WHERE (((Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation1) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled1) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran1) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null));

UNION ALL SELECT Qry_ScheduledItems.Sales_Order_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Customer_Order_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Customer_Name, Qry_ScheduledItems.Ship_To_Location, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Created, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Due, Qry_ScheduledItems.Part_Number, Qry_ScheduledItems.Quantity_Ordered, Qry_JobTicket.Pcs_Ordered, Qry_ScheduledItems.Unit_of_Measure, Qry_ScheduledItems.RIP_Footage, Qry_ScheduledItems.Mould_Footage, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation1 AS Previous_Operation, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran1 AS Previous_Date_Ran, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation2 AS Operation, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled2 AS Date_Scheduled, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran2 AS Date_Ran, Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation3 AS Next_Operation, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled3 AS Next_Operation_Date, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran3 AS Next_Operation_Date_Ran, Qry_JobTicket.Raw_Material, Qry_JobTicket.RIP_Width, Qry_JobTicket.BD_FTG, Qry_JobTicket.Resaw_Passes, Qry_JobTicket.Yield_Cut, Qry_JobTicket.Lumber_Notes, Qry_JobTicket.Sheet_Size, Qry_JobTicket.Optimal_RIP_Size, Qry_JobTicket.Required_RIP_Size, Qry_JobTicket.Off_Fall, Qry_JobTicket.Pieces, Qry_JobTicket.Cuts_Per_Sheet, Qry_JobTicket.Sheets_Needed, Qry_ScheduledItems.RIP_Quantity, Qry_JobTicket.Profile_Size, Qry_JobTicket.Moulder_Number, Qry_JobTicket.Number_Of_Passes, Qry_JobTicket.Moulder_Notes, Qry_ScheduledItems.Mould_Quantity, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Number1, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Color1, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Slit1, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_SQFTG1, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Number2, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Color2, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Slit2, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_SQFTG2, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Number3, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Color3, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_Slit3, Qry_JobTicket.Wrap_SQFTG3, Qry_ScheduledItems.Wrap_Quantity, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Number1, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Color1, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Slit1, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_SQFTG1, Qry_JobTicket.Foil1_Number_Slits, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Number2, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Color2, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Slit2, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_SQFTG2, Qry_JobTicket.Foil2_Number_Slits, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Number3, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Color3, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Slit3, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_SQFTG3, Qry_JobTicket.Foil3_Number_Slits, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Number4, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Color4, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_Slit4, Qry_JobTicket.Foil_SQFTG4, Qry_JobTicket.Foil4_Number_Slits, Qry_JobTicket.[Wrap/Foil_Notes], Qry_JobTicket.Finish_Number, Qry_JobTicket.Step1, Qry_JobTicket.Step2, Qry_JobTicket.Step3, Qry_JobTicket.Step4, Qry_JobTicket.Step5, Qry_JobTicket.Step6, Qry_JobTicket.Step7, Qry_JobTicket.Step8, Qry_JobTicket.Step9, Qry_JobTicket.Step10, Qry_JobTicket.Paint_Notes, Qry_ScheduledItems.Paint_Quantity, Qry_JobTicket.Assembly_Notes, Qry_JobTicket.Package_Notes, Qry_JobTicket.Order_Notes, Qry_ScheduledItems.Pack_Quantity, Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped
FROM Qry_JobTicket INNER JOIN Qry_ScheduledItems ON Qry_JobTicket.Sales_Order_Number = Qry_ScheduledItems.Sales_Order_Number
WHERE (((Qry_ScheduledItems.Operation2) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Scheduled2) Is Not Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Ran2) Is Null) AND ((Qry_ScheduledItems.Date_Shipped) Is Null));
```

** Sorry about the Code Boxes, I cannot figure out how to get them to wrap text **

Answer (score 1):

The limit is 255 *output* fields. From where these origin doesn't matter.

However, the query itself has a total limit of characters. You can save dramatically on that by using *alias*, like:

```
FROM Qry_JobTicket As J INNER JOIN Qry_ScheduledItems As S On J.Sales_Order_number = ...
```

Comment: I have attempted this alias change, and I am still getting the 'too many fields defined' error. This cut out ~19,000 total characters. My working Union has 37,800 characters, and this one is only sitting at 23,492, so I don't think this is where the issue stems from. This change did make it much more readable for me, so thank you for that though!

Comment: OK. Then, instead of one huge union query, cut it into, say, four subqueries which you colledt in one final query.